# Stying React JS Elements outside render's return

Tags: reactjs, styling

I have the following React JS component.

```
export class Sample {
  render() {
    let sampleFruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange"];
    let fruits = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sampleFruits.length; i++) {
      fruits.push(<div className="fruit">{sampleFruits[i]}</div>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="hello">Hello</h1>
        <div>{fruits}</div>
        <style jsx>
          {`
            .hello {
              font-size: 18px;
              color: #f00;
            }
            .fruit {
              color: #0f0;
            }
          `}
        </style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code, style gets applied only to .hello, where .fruit doesn't get the style.
Any suggestions on styling this, apart from using jsx global?

Comment: are you sure? I copy pasted your code into a CodeSandbox and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/10k3wkpn5q?fontsize=14

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? [It seems to work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/23oyx01rpj).

Comment: Yes. it doesnt seem to work. I am using Next framework for react

Answer (score -2):

You could just include the style when you declare the `div`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < sampleFruits.length; i++) {
      fruits.push(<div className="fruit" style={{ color: '#0f0' }}>{sampleFruits[i]}</div>);
    }
```